# How can the last updated packages get propagated earlier than the first updated packages

Tags: packages, texlive, updating, pst-plot

I often experience the following phenomenon. For example,

from [texnik.dante.de/tex/generic](http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/?C=M;O=D) I noticed that

- `pst-plot` gets updated on August 24, 2014
- `pst-poly` gets updated on August 28, 2014

and then I synced my installed TeXLive 2014 with the DANTE mirror (and some others).

The strange things happened where I got the latest `pst-poly` but my `pst-plot` is still old (not updated).

### Questions

- Why can this strange thing happen?
- How to solve it?

Comment: Last Update, First Propagated. It behaves like a stack.

Comment: things get added to texlive after they have been added to ctan by volunteers doing work, so things happen when they happen.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Up to now, I still don't understand the workflow of a package from when it is written/updated (by an author) to when it is available in mirrors. So my questions are chronologically: (1).For example, an author updates a package and upload it to `texnik.DANTE.de/tex/generic`. Does this update become a master file which will be duplicated by other mirrors?  (2) After, the author upload the updated package, does he/she also need to make an extra configuration such that it can be used by TeXLive and MikTeX and others? Is such an configuration identical for TeXLive, MikTeX, & other?

Comment: These days many package authors keep their development versions in public archives, but that does not mean that any files that are there are ready to go to ctan. The package author needs to explicitly upload files to ctan, it then requires volunteer labour of the ctan organisers to install it on a ctan host, it then takes a couple of days to reach all ctan mirrors and then it requires volunteer labour of the miktex and texlive maintainers to take a copy off ctan and check it in to the distribution sources and update the metadata so that it is included in distribution updates to users.

Comment: Concerning how to get things into TL, see page 56 or soof my old slides https://www.preining.info/talks/cstug08.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an updated package should be announced by the CTAN maintainers is a decision of the package author. If he/she enables the button `no announcment needed` while uploading a new version a default TeXLive/MikTeX user will notice such an update only when he/she updates his/her TeX distribution.

http://texnik.dante.de/ has *nothing* to do with CTAN. It is a *private* area for experimental package updates or new packages. However, all packages listed there will be sooner or later part of CTAN.

Comment: Sorry. So CTAN maintainers will sync CTAN with texnik.dante.de or otherwise the PSTricks author upload the packages from texnik.dante.de to CTAN?In my understanding, texnik.dante.de is the master files that will be duplicated by CTAN and then propagated to other mirrors around the globe.

Comment: CTAN maintainers will organize packages which are uploaded to CTAN, that's all. And that has nothing to do with texnik.dante.de, as I already wrote.